# audioSession.inputIsAvailable = NO in 2nd Generation iPod Touch 4.2.1

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, avfoundation, avaudiorecorder, avaudiosession

I'm trying to record the voice of the user using AVAudioRecorder class.
First of all I set the AudioSession

```
AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
NSError *error;
if ([audioSession inputIsAvailable]) {
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord error:&error];
}
```

The value of audioSession.inputIsAvailable is always NO for my 2nd Gen iPod Touch.
Why does it happen? Is not possible to record with this device? Or does it depend on the OS?

Comment: When I insert the headphones in the iPod inputIsAvailable = YES and the recording works!!